# Include an existing letter into and existing document

Tags: latex

I'm very new to latex so please forgive me if I'm asking a question easily solved. I tried searching all over for an answer but couldn't find one.

I have two existing latex documents, a letter and a report. Is there any simple way to easily include the letter in the report? I know it is possible to compile a pdf version of the letter and to simply include the pdf in the report, but is it possible to do it otherwise?

UPDATE:

I could not find a solution so I ended up compiling the letter to pdf and then including the resultant pdf.

Comment: I voted to migrate to SuperUser, but actually TeX.StackExchange.Com is more appropriate, but unfortunately you cannot vote for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find a solution so I ended up compiling the letter to pdf and then including the resultant pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Try `\input{filename}` or `\include{filename}`.

Comment: That won't work for me since my letter uses the letter documentclass and the report uses the report documentcass. At least it gives me a compile error. Is it possible to include files of different document classes?

Comment: I assumed that you'd remove `\documentclass` declaration (and the rest of preamble) from one of your files. But if the distinction between classes matters for you, I don't think there's an easy way to go (unless someone has written a package for that).